# warpPerspective

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

**I tried to get the inverse perspective to get a frame captured in real-time to the camera plane using the following code:**

```
Mat dst;
    dst=dst.zeros(frame.cols,frame.rows,frame.type());  

    if(Found){

     Mat mmat;
     mmat.create(3,3,CV_32FC1);
     mmat=getPerspectiveTransform(templPoints,imgPoints);
     cout<< mmat<<endl<<endl;
     warpPerspective(frame,dst,Homo,dst.size(),INTER_LINEAR );
     imshow("out",dst);
    }
```

**the problem is that the dst image is totally black , what's wrong with my code?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you are seeing is usually the result of sending the source points  into `getPerspectiveTransform` in the wrong order. This means that the points are crossing each other and triangular shapes will appear. Check the order of the points and make sure they match the order of the destination points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide some more details. 
Why are you calling both findHomography and getPerspectiveTransform? Since you are calling both, I assume that both templPoints and imgPoints are of size 4, in which case the call to findHomography is redundant (and RANSAC does nothing at all for you).

Have you looked (e.g. using matlab or octave, or by hand) at the values of mmat * templPoints? They should be equal to imgPoints, and all inside the [0, dst.width] x [0, dst.height]